# Show Listview Scroll Current Possion

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using `ListView` and i have 20 records inside it, when i scroll `ListView`  **i needs current position of `ListView` row**,

i am using this code but it gives me only start and end position

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {



                Log.e("Scroll",
                        "Scroll First=="
                                + arraylist.get(firstVisibleItem)
                                        .getAcronyms());
                char firststring = arraylist.get(firstVisibleItem)
                        .getAcronyms().charAt(0);

                tvLatter.setText("" + firststring);
                if (lvAcronyms.getLastVisiblePosition() == lvAcronyms
                        .getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                        && lvAcronyms.getChildAt(
                                lvAcronyms.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= lvAcronyms
                                .getHeight()) {
                    Log.e("Scroll",
                            "Scroll First=="
                                    + arraylist.get(adapter.getCount() - 1)
                                            .getAcronyms());
                    char first = arraylist.get(adapter.getCount() - 1)
                            .getAcronyms().charAt(0);
                    tvLatter.setText("" + first);
                }
        }
```

Comment: onClick or what because at a time there can be multiple items on screen.

Comment: nope not on click , do you seen inside contact scrolling , i needs like this , but only position not ui,

Comment: din''t get attach some screenshot